# How to highlight the word "base" as code with the listings package, e. g. \lstinline{base}?

Tags: listings, code

When I use the word `base` inside `\lstinline{}` to highlight it as inline code, I get an error, followed by warnings that are not there, if the error is not there:

```
Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `yac'. \lstinline{base}
Usage of package `parskip' together(scrreprt) with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
\float@addtolists detected!(scrreprt) Implementation of \float@addtolist became(scrreprt) deprecated in KOMA-Script v3.01 2008/11/14 and(scrreprt) has been replaced by several more flexible(scrreprt) features of package `tocbasic`.
Overfull \hbox (0.64577pt too wide) in paragraph
\float@listhead detected!(scrreprt) Implementation of \float@listhead became(scrreprt) deprecated in KOMA-Script v3.01 2008/11/14 and(scrreprt) has been replaced by several more flexible(scrreprt) features of package `tocbasic`.
```

I get this error when I use `\lstinline{base}`, `\lstinline{<base>}` or `\lstinline{a base}`, but not with `\lstinline{Base}` or `\lstinline{abase}`. So I'm whondering, is `base` a reserved word? How can I highlight it with the `listings` package? Btw. `base` is an HTML element.

MCRE:

```tex
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    emph={square}, 
    emphstyle=\color{blue}\texttt,
    emph={[2]root,base},
    emphstyle={[2]\color{yac}\texttt}
}

\begin{document}
    No error: \lstinline{Base} 
    
    Error: \lstinline{base}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is not related ith base or Base. It is related with hoy you define lstset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It his what you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    emph={square}, 
    emphstyle=\color{blue}\texttt,
    emph={[2]root,base},
    emphstyle={[2]\color{red}\texttt},
}

\begin{document}
    No error: \lstinline{square} 
    
    Error: \lstinline{base}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Ok, I get it. Little background: The code is from a template I have to use. It looks like the authors wanted to highlight the words `square`, `root` and `base` differently. And as `base` needs the color `yac`, that does not exist, there was an error thrown whenever I used it. Actually, I do not need this extra highlighting at all. So I deleted all the `emph*` lines. Thanks for pointing me to this.